# Combine time and timestamp to select timed data in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, scheduling, sql-timestamp, medoo

I have two columns in my MySql database 
activeAt(timestamp)
activeAtTime(time)

I want to fetch data that are less than activeAtTime(timestamp) and activeAt(time)

The problem I'm facing in my code is
if activeAt is 25th may & activeAtTime is 5pm of an particular post
and If the fetch the data with below code at 26th may 2pm it is not getting listed, but if i fetch at 26th may 5:30 pm the post is getting listed

*(i used medoo, but you can suggest any query)*

```
 "activeAt[<=]" => date("Y-m-d"),
 "activeAtTime[<=]" => date("H:i")
```

eg a post with activeAt and activeAtTime

If i make a fetch request at 25th may, 8 am this post is not getting listed

I'm trying to make a blogs that posts based on scheduled time and date
i tried bootstrap datetime picker but it didn't work
Is there any way i can combine activeAt and ActiveATtime
So that the above logic works
What will be the most efficient way to do it?.

Comment: _“What will be the most efficient way to do it?”_ - to not store date and time as two separate values to begin with.

Comment: Otherwise, you will have to extend your condition accordingly - to select records that either have the date <= the current date, or the date == the current date AND the active time <= the current time.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. It's daft, pointless, and irritating.

Comment: *I want to fetch data that are less than activeAtTime(timestamp) and activeAt(time)* Combine this two column values into one DATETIME or TIMESTAMP value using ADDTIME() or TIMESTAMP() function.

Comment: @CBroe, but from html i have only type="date" and type="time", I want help on joining them in single data where i can store it as an timestamp

Comment: Don’t just say “I want help”, explain what _exactly_ you need help with then.

Comment: a way to join $_POST["activeDate"]  and $_POST["activeTime"] from 
<input type="date" name="activeDate" /> & <input type="time" name="activeTime" />
respectively so that i store them in activeAt in mysql database as timestamp